# How can I correctly compare two datetimes in my blade file?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to compare two dates from my blade file, and it works completely fine in my local project and provides correct outcome right by the second, but in the live site, there is a delay in the comparison and it shows the correct result after about one minute. Below is my code in the blade file.

```
@if (strtotime($timest->format('M-d-y g:i:s')) >strtotime(\carbon\carbon::now('EST5EDT')->format('M-d-y g:i:s')))
    <span class="badge badge-primary">Will Publish At {{ $timest->format('M-d-y g:i:s a') }}</span>
@else
    <span class="badge badge-success">Published AT {{ $timest->format('M-d-y g:i:s a') }}</span>
@endif
```

Comment: "shows the correct result after about **one minute**" Any idea why the 1 min delay?

Comment: @Digvijay is asking the right question here. There is no reason I can see that there would be a 1 minute delay "in the comparison".

Comment: If you can provide some more debugging information about the 1 minute delay, and my solution below does not solve it for you, I will delete my answer and look into it more.

Comment: thank you for the replies guys, the issue is that it is working fine in my local project but in the live one, it takes a one minute delay to show the correct display

Comment: You REALLY need to clarify what "it takes a one minute delay to show the correct display" means, if you need someone to help you solve this.

Comment: @KurtFriars I just found out for some reason, in the live site, where the time comparison is done, the seconds are not considered

Comment: I just think `$timest` contains a date based on the user clock instead of the server clock, so they may not be exactly synchronized. You should compare user clock with user clock or server clock with server clock to get a precise comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carbon's [built in compare methods](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) like so, for a 'greater than' comparison:

```
@if($timest->gt(Carbon\Carbon::now('EST5EDT'))
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, I tried this one as well but it still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Use `isFuture` or `isPast` methods from Carbon:

```
@if ($timest->isFuture())
   Will Publish At {{ $timest->format('M-d-y g:i:s a') }}
@else
   Published AT {{ $timest->format('M-d-y g:i:s a') }}
@endif
```

If you need to take some advance, you can replace `$timest` with `$timest->addMinutes(2)`

But more likely your problem is `$timest` contains a date based on the user clock instead of the server clock, so they may not be exactly synchronized. You should compare user clock with user clock or server clock with server clock to get a precise comparison.